# deepcopy but only the pointer of the list not the pointers of what's inside

Tags: python, pointers

Here is a minimal reproducible code to give an example:

```
L = [1]
M = [1]
N = [L, M]
from copy import deepcopy
A = deepcopy(N)
A[0][0] = "ll"
L  # I want this to become ["ll"]
Out[8]: [1]
A
Out[9]: ["ll", [1]]
```

I would want to make a deepcopy of N so that when I modify A (adding an element, removing one), it doesn't affect N. This works. But I also want the following behaviour: if I modify N[0] i.e. L, I want it to modify A[0] too because I would want those two pointers to point at the same thing.

Is this achievable other than with:

```
A = [n for n in N]
```

?
Is it bad practice to do so?

Here is a minimal reproducible example to show that it works:

```
L = [1]
M = [1]
N = [L, M]
A = [n for n in N]
A[0][0] = "ll"
L
Out[7]: ['ll']
A.remove(L)
A
Out[9]: [[1]]
N
Out[10]: [['ll'], [1]]
```

If not, what are the good practices regarding such a problem?

Comment: The whole point of deep copy is to prevent that from happening. Use a shallow copy if you want to keep references to the nested lists.

Comment: Use `A = N.copy()`

Comment: Oh, I thought `A = N.copy()` and `A = N` were the same. just realized they weren't

Comment: Is there a difference between `A = N.copy()` and `A = [n for n in N]` then?

Comment: No difference other than performance.

Comment: The latter being longer I assume?

Comment: I checked, and yes, the latter is around 1/3 longer if `N = [[1], [2], [3]]`

Comment: `N.copy()` is 8 characters, `[n for n in N]` is 14 characters. That's 75% longer.

Comment: I meant longer time-wise haha